# How to check if two times overlap in PHP?

Tags: php, time, compare, unix-timestamp

So I'm trying to figure out how to check if two times overlap using PHP and a MySQL database.

This is the function I'm using to check if they are overlapping:

```
function testRange($start_time1,$end_time1,$start_time2,$end_time2) {
    return ($end_time1 < $start_time2) ? false : ($start_time1 > $start_time2) && ($start_time1 > $end_time2) ?  false : true;
}
```

AFAIK that should work fine so I go to check if the times are overlapping and add any that do overlap to an array:

```
$clashes = [];
$idTracker = [];
foreach ($userBands as $show) {
    foreach ($userBands as $show1) {
        if(!($show->id == $show1->id)) {
            if(strcmp($show->date, $show1->date) == 0 && testRange(strtotime($show->time), strtotime($show->time) + ($show->length*60), strtotime($show1->time), strtotime($show1->time) + ($show1->length*60))) {
                array_push($clashes, [
                    "s1_id" => $show->id,
                    "s2_id" => $show1->id
                ]);
            }
        }
    }
}

foreach ($clashes as $clash) {
    foreach ($clashes as $clash1) {                  
        //If Clash1->ID1 == Clash2->ID1 then
    }
    print_r($clash);
    echo "<br>";
}
```

However when I print out the entries of the $clashes array I get this as my output:
[image: Output]

which is just wrong completely as this is the contents of the database:
[image: Database]

27 and 26 should not be clashing with 25, but they are being tracked into the $clashes array. Why is this happening?

Database Info:

Date is of the Date SQL type, Time is of the Time SQL type and Length is a double(8,2) SQL type

$userBands Info:

The $userBands variable is a Laravel collection of the Show model

Comment: can you please provide the mysql(i assume) data about the data-types you chose to columns `date`,`time`, and `length` ? it will greatly help, i i suspect, that the phpMyAdmin, is not showing the data as the php script reads it...

Comment: The $userBands variable is a Laravel collection of the Show model.

Comment: Date is of the Date SQL type, Time is of the Time SQL type and Length is a double(8,2) SQL type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by changing the algorithm for comparing the times.

New version:

```
function testRange($s1, $e1, $s2, $e2) {
    return $s1 <= $e2 && $s2 <= $e1;
}
```

Don't know why this works over the previous one however.

Answer (score 1):

First:
You can change the SQL query to get end-time like so:

```
SELECT *, 
ADDTIME(
  CONCAT(time,'.0'), 
  CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT( length DIV 60, ':' ), length MOD 60) ,':0.0') 
) AS EndTime 
FROM `table`;
```

So now you have a column named EndTime,

So this code can work:

```
if(strcmp($show->date, $show1->date) == 0 &&
   newTestRange(
      strtotime($show->time), 
      strtotime($show->EndTime), 
      strtotime($show1->time), 
      strtotime($show1->EndTime) 
      ) ) {
```

I have no idea why this works:

```
function newTestRange($start_time1,$end_time1,$start_time2,$end_time2) {
 //                   12:30:00    13:20:00   12:45:00     13:45:00
// return ($end_time1 < $start_time2) ? false : ($start_time1 > $start_time2) && ($start_time1 > $end_time2) ?  false : true;
    $ret = false; // its all okay.
    if ($start_time1 < $start_time2 ){
        if ($end_time1 > $start_time2 ){
            $ret = true;echo "\n case1-$start_time1-colide-$start_time2 \n";
        }
    } else if ($end_time2 > $start_time1){
        $ret = true; echo "\n case2-$start_time1-colide-$start_time2 \n";
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

but you must consider 4 different scenarios:
[image]

So if one event contains another event, you will find it.

Best!